# Docker resolving service NGINX with docker NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx, laradock

After installing `Docker` on server and `LaraDock`. i'm trying to use dockerized `Laravel` project, as i have installed `nginx` on server i have that on `laradock` too then when upping project i get this error:

```
Recreating laradock_nginx_1 ... error

ERROR: for laradock_nginx_1  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint laradock_nginx_1 (0fa283c2e82aa1ccf59d3ccfbf2d25f44e17239e1ad74f3471c1f964d87884d1): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use
```

I'm new in `Docker` and i'm don't know how can i resolve this problem. i tired to change `nginx` host http and port to 8080 like with this line

```
NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT=80
```

but it coldn't resolve my problem

`nginx` default configuration:

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    # For https
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server ipv6only=on;
    # ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/default.crt;
    # ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/default.key;

    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fixes timeouts
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

`nginx` DockerFile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

LABEL maintainer="Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>"

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

# If you're in China, or you need to change sources, will be set CHANGE_SOURCE to true in .env.

ARG CHANGE_SOURCE=false
RUN if [ ${CHANGE_SOURCE} = true ]; then \
    # Change application source from dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org to aliyun source
    sed -i 's/dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/mirrors.aliyun.com/' /etc/apk/repositories \
;fi

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk --update add logrotate \
    && apk add --no-cache openssl \
    && apk add --no-cache bash

RUN apk add --no-cache curl

RUN set -x ; \
    addgroup -g 82 -S www-data ; \
    adduser -u 82 -D -S -G www-data www-data && exit 0 ; exit 1

ARG PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=php-fpm
ARG PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=9000

# Create 'messages' file used from 'logrotate'
RUN touch /var/log/messages

# Copy 'logrotate' config file
COPY logrotate/nginx /etc/logrotate.d/

# Set upstream conf and remove the default conf
RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server ${PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER}:${PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT}; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf \
    && rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

ADD ./startup.sh /opt/startup.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//g' /opt/startup.sh
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/opt/startup.sh"]

EXPOSE 80 81 443
```

i can't disable server `nginx` and could you please how can i resolve this problem?

**UPDATED:**

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.5'

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}
  backend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}

volumes:
  redis:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  mariadb:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  mongo:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  phpmyadmin:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
  docker-in-docker:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
services:

### Workspace Utilities ##################################
    workspace:
      build:
        context: ./workspace
        args:
          - CHANGE_SOURCE=${CHANGE_SOURCE}
          - SHELL_OH_MY_ZSH=${SHELL_OH_MY_ZSH}
          - SHELL_OH_MY_ZSH_AUTOSUGESTIONS=${SHELL_OH_MY_ZSH_AUTOSUGESTIONS}
          - SHELL_OH_MY_ZSH_ALIASES=${SHELL_OH_MY_ZSH_ALIASES}
          - UBUNTU_SOURCE=${UBUNTU_SOURCE}
          - BASE_IMAGE_TAG_PREFIX=${WORKSPACE_BASE_IMAGE_TAG_PREFIX}
          - LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
          - LARADOCK_PHALCON_VERSION=${PHALCON_VERSION}
          - INSTALL_SUBVERSION=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SUBVERSION}
          - INSTALL_BZ2=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_BZ2}
          - INSTALL_GMP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_GMP}
          - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
          - INSTALL_PCOV=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PCOV}
          - INSTALL_PHPDBG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPDBG}
          - INSTALL_BLACKFIRE=${INSTALL_BLACKFIRE}
          - INSTALL_SSH2=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SSH2}
          - INSTALL_SOAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SOAP}
          - INSTALL_XSL=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XSL}
          - INSTALL_LDAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LDAP}
          - INSTALL_SMB=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SMB}
          - INSTALL_IMAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAP}
          - INSTALL_MONGO=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MONGO}
          - INSTALL_AMQP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AMQP}
          - INSTALL_CASSANDRA=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_CASSANDRA}
          - INSTALL_GEARMAN=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_GEARMAN}
          - INSTALL_PHPREDIS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPREDIS}
          - INSTALL_MSSQL=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MSSQL}
          - NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=${WORKSPACE_NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR}
          - INSTALL_NODE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NODE}
          - NPM_REGISTRY=${WORKSPACE_NPM_REGISTRY}
          - NPM_FETCH_RETRIES=${WORKSPACE_NPM_FETCH_RETRIES}
          - NPM_FETCH_RETRY_FACTOR=${WORKSPACE_NPM_FETCH_RETRY_FACTOR}
          - NPM_FETCH_RETRY_MINTIMEOUT=${WORKSPACE_NPM_FETCH_RETRY_MINTIMEOUT}
          - NPM_FETCH_RETRY_MAXTIMEOUT=${WORKSPACE_NPM_FETCH_RETRY_MAXTIMEOUT}
          - INSTALL_PNPM=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PNPM}
          - INSTALL_YARN=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_YARN}
          - INSTALL_NPM_GULP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_GULP}
          - INSTALL_NPM_BOWER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_BOWER}
          - INSTALL_NPM_VUE_CLI=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_VUE_CLI}
          - INSTALL_NPM_ANGULAR_CLI=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_ANGULAR_CLI}
          - INSTALL_DRUSH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DRUSH}
          - INSTALL_WP_CLI=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_WP_CLI}
          - INSTALL_DRUPAL_CONSOLE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DRUPAL_CONSOLE}
          - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE}
          - INSTALL_OCI8=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_OCI8}
          - INSTALL_V8JS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_V8JS}
          - COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL}
          - COMPOSER_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_VERSION}
          - COMPOSER_AUTH=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_AUTH}
          - COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST}
          - INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH}
          - INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY}
          - INSTALL_LARAVEL_INSTALLER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LARAVEL_INSTALLER}
          - INSTALL_DEPLOYER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DEPLOYER}
          - INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO}
          - INSTALL_LINUXBREW=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LINUXBREW}
          - INSTALL_MC=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MC}
          - INSTALL_SYMFONY=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SYMFONY}
          - INSTALL_PYTHON=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PYTHON}
          - INSTALL_PYTHON3=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PYTHON3}
          - INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS}
          - INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK}
          - INSTALL_TERRAFORM=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_TERRAFORM}
          - INSTALL_DUSK_DEPS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DUSK_DEPS}
          - INSTALL_PG_CLIENT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PG_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_PHALCON=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHALCON}
          - INSTALL_SWOOLE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SWOOLE}
          - INSTALL_TAINT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_TAINT}
          - INSTALL_LIBPNG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LIBPNG}
          - INSTALL_GRAPHVIZ=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_GRAPHVIZ}
          - INSTALL_IONCUBE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IONCUBE}
          - INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_PING=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PING}
          - INSTALL_SSHPASS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SSHPASS}
          - INSTALL_INOTIFY=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_INOTIFY}
          - INSTALL_FSWATCH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_FSWATCH}
          - INSTALL_AST=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AST}
          - INSTALL_YAML=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_YAML}
          - INSTALL_RDKAFKA=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_RDKAFKA}
          - INSTALL_MAILPARSE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MAILPARSE}
          - INSTALL_GIT_PROMPT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_GIT_PROMPT}
          - INSTALL_XMLRPC=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XMLRPC}
          - PUID=${WORKSPACE_PUID}
          - PGID=${WORKSPACE_PGID}
          - CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION}
          - NODE_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_NODE_VERSION}
          - YARN_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_YARN_VERSION}
          - DRUSH_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_DRUSH_VERSION}
          - AST_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_AST_VERSION}
          - IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION}
          - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
          - BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID=${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID}
          - BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN=${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN}
          - INSTALL_POWERLINE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_POWERLINE}
          - INSTALL_SUPERVISOR=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SUPERVISOR}
          - INSTALL_FFMPEG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_FFMPEG}
          - INSTALL_AUDIOWAVEFORM=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AUDIOWAVEFORM}
          - INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF}
          - INSTALL_GNU_PARALLEL=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_GNU_PARALLEL}
          - INSTALL_LNAV=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LNAV}
          - INSTALL_PROTOC=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PROTOC}
          - PROTOC_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_PROTOC_VERSION}
          - INSTALL_DOCKER_CLIENT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DOCKER_CLIENT}
          - http_proxy
          - https_proxy
          - no_proxy
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
        - docker-in-docker:/certs/client
        - ./php-worker/supervisord.d:/etc/supervisord.d
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      ports:
        - "${WORKSPACE_SSH_PORT}:22"
        - "${WORKSPACE_BROWSERSYNC_HOST_PORT}:3000"
        - "${WORKSPACE_BROWSERSYNC_UI_HOST_PORT}:3001"
        - "${WORKSPACE_VUE_CLI_SERVE_HOST_PORT}:8080"
        - "${WORKSPACE_VUE_CLI_UI_HOST_PORT}:8000"
        - "${WORKSPACE_ANGULAR_CLI_SERVE_HOST_PORT}:4200"
      tty: true
      environment:
        - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=${PHP_IDE_CONFIG}
        - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker-in-docker:2376
        - DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
        - DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs
        - DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend
      links:
        - docker-in-docker

### PHP-FPM ##############################################
    php-fpm:
      build:
        context: ./php-fpm
        args:
          - CHANGE_SOURCE=${CHANGE_SOURCE}
          - BASE_IMAGE_TAG_PREFIX=${PHP_FPM_BASE_IMAGE_TAG_PREFIX}
          - LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
          - LARADOCK_PHALCON_VERSION=${PHALCON_VERSION}
          - INSTALL_BZ2=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_BZ2}
          - INSTALL_GMP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GMP}
          - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
          - INSTALL_PCOV=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PCOV}
          - INSTALL_PHPDBG=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPDBG}
          - INSTALL_BLACKFIRE=${INSTALL_BLACKFIRE}
          - INSTALL_SSH2=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SSH2}
          - INSTALL_SOAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SOAP}
          - INSTALL_XSL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XSL}
          - INSTALL_SMB=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SMB}
          - INSTALL_IMAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAP}
          - INSTALL_MONGO=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MONGO}
          - INSTALL_AMQP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_AMQP}
          - INSTALL_CASSANDRA=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_CASSANDRA}
          - INSTALL_GEARMAN=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GEARMAN}
          - INSTALL_MSSQL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MSSQL}
          - INSTALL_BCMATH=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_BCMATH}
          - INSTALL_PHPREDIS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHPREDIS}
          - INSTALL_MEMCACHED=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MEMCACHED}
          - INSTALL_OPCACHE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_OPCACHE}
          - INSTALL_EXIF=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_EXIF}
          - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE}
          - INSTALL_OCI8=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_OCI8}
          - INSTALL_MYSQLI=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MYSQLI}
          - INSTALL_PGSQL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PGSQL}
          - INSTALL_PG_CLIENT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PG_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_POSTGIS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_POSTGIS}
          - INSTALL_INTL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_INTL}
          - INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT}
          - INSTALL_LDAP=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_LDAP}
          - INSTALL_PHALCON=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PHALCON}
          - INSTALL_SWOOLE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SWOOLE}
          - INSTALL_TAINT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_TAINT}
          - INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS}
          - INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK}
          - INSTALL_CALENDAR=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_CALENDAR}
          - INSTALL_FAKETIME=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_FAKETIME}
          - INSTALL_IONCUBE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_IONCUBE}
          - INSTALL_APCU=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_APCU}
          - INSTALL_CACHETOOL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_CACHETOOL}
          - INSTALL_YAML=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_YAML}
          - INSTALL_RDKAFKA=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_RDKAFKA}
          - INSTALL_GETTEXT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_GETTEXT}
          - INSTALL_ADDITIONAL_LOCALES=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_ADDITIONAL_LOCALES}
          - INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_PING=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PING}
          - INSTALL_SSHPASS=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_SSHPASS}
          - INSTALL_MAILPARSE=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_MAILPARSE}
          - INSTALL_PCNTL=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_PCNTL}
          - ADDITIONAL_LOCALES=${PHP_FPM_ADDITIONAL_LOCALES}
          - INSTALL_FFMPEG=${PHP_FPM_FFMPEG}
          - INSTALL_AUDIOWAVEFORM=${PHP_FPM_AUDIOWAVEFORM}
          - INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF}
          - INSTALL_XHPROF=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XHPROF}
          - INSTALL_XMLRPC=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_XMLRPC}
          - DOWNGRADE_OPENSSL_TLS_AND_SECLEVEL=${PHP_DOWNGRADE_OPENSSL_TLS_AND_SECLEVEL}
          - PUID=${PHP_FPM_PUID}
          - PGID=${PHP_FPM_PGID}
          - IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION=${PHP_FPM_IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION}
          - LOCALE=${PHP_FPM_DEFAULT_LOCALE}
          - PHP_FPM_NEW_RELIC=${PHP_FPM_NEW_RELIC}
          - PHP_FPM_NEW_RELIC_KEY=${PHP_FPM_NEW_RELIC_KEY}
          - PHP_FPM_NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME=${PHP_FPM_NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME}
          - INSTALL_DOCKER_CLIENT=${PHP_FPM_INSTALL_DOCKER_CLIENT}
          - http_proxy
          - https_proxy
          - no_proxy
      volumes:
        - ./php-fpm/php${PHP_VERSION}.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
        - docker-in-docker:/certs/client
      ports:
        - "${PHP_FPM_XDEBUG_PORT}:9003"
      expose:
        - "9000"
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      environment:
        - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=${PHP_IDE_CONFIG}
        - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker-in-docker:2376
        - DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
        - DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs
        - DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client
        - FAKETIME=${PHP_FPM_FAKETIME}
      depends_on:
        - workspace
      networks:
        - backend
      links:
        - docker-in-docker

### PHP Worker ############################################
    php-worker:
      build:
        context: ./php-worker
        args:
          - CHANGE_SOURCE=${CHANGE_SOURCE}
          - LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
          - PHALCON_VERSION=${PHALCON_VERSION}
          - INSTALL_BZ2=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_BZ2}
          - INSTALL_GD=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_GD}
          - INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK}
          - INSTALL_GMP=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_GMP}
          - INSTALL_PGSQL=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_PGSQL}
          - INSTALL_MONGO=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_MONGO}
          - INSTALL_BCMATH=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_BCMATH}
          - INSTALL_OCI8=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_OCI8}
          - INSTALL_PHALCON=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_PHALCON}
          - INSTALL_SOAP=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_SOAP}
          - INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_ZIP_ARCHIVE}
          - INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_AMQP=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_AMQP}
          - INSTALL_CASSANDRA=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_CASSANDRA}
          - INSTALL_GEARMAN=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_GEARMAN}
          - INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_GHOSTSCRIPT}
          - INSTALL_SWOOLE=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_SWOOLE}
          - INSTALL_TAINT=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_TAINT}
          - INSTALL_FFMPEG=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_FFMPEG}
          - INSTALL_AUDIOWAVEFORM=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_AUDIOWAVEFORM}
          - INSTALL_REDIS=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_REDIS}
          - INSTALL_IMAP=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_IMAP}
          - INSTALL_XMLRPC=${PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_XMLRPC}
          - PUID=${PHP_WORKER_PUID}
          - PGID=${PHP_WORKER_PGID}
          - IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION=${PHP_WORKER_IMAGEMAGICK_VERSION}
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
        - ./php-worker/supervisord.d:/etc/supervisord.d
      depends_on:
        - workspace
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      networks:
        - backend

### NGINX Server #########################################
    nginx:
      build:
        context: ./nginx
        args:
          - CHANGE_SOURCE=${CHANGE_SOURCE}
          - PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER}
          - PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=${NGINX_PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT}
          - http_proxy
          - https_proxy
          - no_proxy
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
        - ${NGINX_HOST_LOG_PATH}:/var/log/nginx
        - ${NGINX_SITES_PATH}:/etc/nginx/sites-available
        - ${NGINX_SSL_PATH}:/etc/nginx/ssl
      ports:
        - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80"
        - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTPS_PORT}:443"
        - "${VARNISH_BACKEND_PORT}:81"
      depends_on:
        - php-fpm
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend

### MariaDB ##############################################
    mariadb:
      build:
        context: ./mariadb
        args:
          - http_proxy
          - https_proxy
          - no_proxy
          - MARIADB_VERSION=${MARIADB_VERSION}
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
        - ${MARIADB_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      ports:
        - "${MARIADB_PORT}:3306"
      environment:
        - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MARIADB_DATABASE}
        - MYSQL_USER=${MARIADB_USER}
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MARIADB_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      networks:
        - backend

### MongoDB ##############################################
    mongo:
      build: ./mongo
      ports:
        - "${MONGODB_PORT}:27017"
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mongo:/data/db
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/mongo_config:/data/configdb
      networks:
        - backend

### Redis ################################################
    redis:
      build: ./redis
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/redis:/data
      ports:
        - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
      networks:
        - backend

### phpMyAdmin ###########################################
    phpmyadmin:
      build: ./phpmyadmin
      environment:
        - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
        - MYSQL_USER=${PMA_USER}
        - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${PMA_PASSWORD}
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${PMA_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        - MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=${PMA_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME}
        - MEMORY_LIMIT=${PMA_MEMORY_LIMIT}
        - UPLOAD_LIMIT=${PMA_UPLOAD_LIMIT}
      ports:
        - "${PMA_PORT}:80"
      depends_on:
        - "${PMA_DB_ENGINE}"
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend

### Laravel Echo Server #######################################
    laravel-echo-server:
      build:
        context: ./laravel-echo-server
        args:
          - CHANGE_SOURCE=${CHANGE_SOURCE}
      volumes:
        - ./laravel-echo-server/laravel-echo-server.json:/app/laravel-echo-server.json:ro
      ports:
        - "${LARAVEL_ECHO_SERVER_PORT}:6001"
      links:
        - redis
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend

### Docker-in-Docker ################################################
    docker-in-docker:
      image: docker:19.03-dind
      environment:
        DOCKER_TLS_SAN: DNS:docker-in-docker
      privileged: true
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}
        - docker-in-docker:/certs/client
      expose:
        - 2375
      networks:
        - backend
```

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile(s)?

Comment: @MarkoE I updated post with `nginx` DockerFile

Comment: The error suggests a docker-compose.yml file... can you also post that one?

Comment: @Ivonet yes, my post updated, please review again

Comment: Why can you not stop or uninstall the `nginx` service on your host machine? The error you're getting is basically telling you that you can't forward port `443` on your host machine becuase it is already in use (by `nginx`).

Comment: @Peppermintology because i have many published site and all of them are using server own nginx, stopping server `nginx`. stopping nginx server doesn't make any problem? can other sites use docker `nginx` while upped ?

Comment: If you have non docker sites using the local `nginx` service then I'd agree you can't stop the service. :p

Answer (score 4):

I saw the project you mentioned [LaraDock](https://github.com/laradock/laradock), so I am assuming this is where the `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` came from.

---

First of all, let's solve the problem, there is 2 information in the error message:

1. Recreating laradock_nginx_1
2. listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use

Here is the clue to fix those:

#### Clean up previous Containers

for fixing `Recreating laradock_nginx_1`

1. Make sure the previous `Nginx container` is clean up, the should be automatically done by the `docker-compose for most cases, but you can always it manually:

   1. make sure the is nothing important inside those containers
   2. `docker-compose kill && docker-compose rm`

#### Make sure the target port available

for fixing `listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use`

There should always be no port problem inside a container, so you have to make check the port on the `host machine`, run this on your server, and check out which progress has taken the `443` port:

1. `netstat -apn | grep 443`
2. kill that progress if you can

---

As the `change Nginx host port to 8080` part.

Docker uses a [Bridge Network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) by default, Each Container will have its own network namespace, which means every network configuration you modified happened inside the container and has nearly nothing to do with the network on your server.

If you want to change the binding port on your server, you should change the `docker-compose.yml`, for example, [here](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L407), this will make docker-compose binding the port inside your Nginx container to a new one on your server